# How to properly configure the Audio?

Tags: sound

If i connect my headphones the speaker still work is that a bug? or that suppose to happen just like that that never happen to me before.

Comment: Can you be more specific and add more detail? I am having a hard time understanding your question, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is a bug.

You can try to install the `linux-backports-modules-alsa` package and then see if the problem still exists after a reboot.

If that doesn't fix it, please run the following command, and follow the instructions:

```
ubuntu-bug alsa-base
```

This will collect info about your audio hardware & software configuration, ask some questions, and submit this to the bugtracker on Launchpad (if you don't have a Launchpad account yet, you will be asked to create one).  Once you are on Launchpad, make sure you add a clear description of the problem.  E.g. if it worked in earlier Ubuntu-versions, pleas tell which one(s).